# Image is showing on simulator but not on a real iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

So I got this piece of code, I want to show a picture on my view:

```
imgLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[imgLogo setFrame:CGRectMake(60, 200, 200, 200)];
[imgLogo setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyFrigginAwesomeLogo"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgLogo];
```

But the problem is that it works correctly when testing it on the simulator(iOS 7) but it doesn't show anything on my iPhone(4S with iOS7) itself.

Comment: check build settings, might not have added the image to the bundle properly

Comment: Check case of logo.  The device is case sensitive, the simulator is not.

Comment: @Putz1103 That was it, it was indeed case sensitive :) !

Comment: @Monolo aren't nearly all programming questions about a typing error in a round about way? If one doesn't know that iOS devices are case sensitive, this post will definitely help.

Comment: In my case it had a space instead of an underscore... " " ... "_" but why? shouldn't it "simulate" the real behavior?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answer added from Comment:

The iOS devices are case sensitive, but the simulator is not.  Make sure you are trying to load the exact filename in order for them to be found.

Comment: Thanks, if stackoverflow didn't exist I would've never found this answer. ;)

Comment: Where in the world is this stated in the documentation?!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the designated initializer for `UIImageView` instead of just `init`:

```
NSString *logoName = @"MyFriggingAwesomeLogo";
imgLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:logoName]];
imgLogo.frame = CGRectOffset(imgLogo.frame, 60, 200);
[self.view addSubview:imgLogo];
```

It's also possible that you've added the image resource to only the simulator target. In your bundle settings Build Phases, make sure you have the image listed in Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: Just `init` with calling `setImage` and `initWithImage` are exactly the same if you call them right behind each other like in my example.